# Writing C# code to use aspnet_regiis functionality from encryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I have a load of C# code that runs aspnet_regiis from the command line using the following type of code:

```
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(aspRegPath, arguments);
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        ....
```

Then I was trying see if I can do the same fnctionality using regular .NET classes. I was able to use .NET classes for the encryption and decryption stuff aspnet_regiis was doing using something like:

```
        ConfigurationSection section = configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RSAKey");
        configuration.Save();
```

But i can't find .NET classes to do the other functionality i.e.

```
        //Delete container
        aspnet_regiis -pz RSAKey

        //Create the container
        aspnet_regiis -pc RSAKey-exp

        //Install the key into a machine-level RSA key provider called DealAxisRSAKey
        aspnet_regiis -pi RSAKey pathToKeyFile

        //Grant access to the contrainer
        aspnet_regiis -pa RSAKey "NT Authority\Network service"
```

Anyone know if this is possible? Or do I have to use aspnet_regiis?

Comment: you want a .net class that does aspnet_iisreg functionality so you dont have to make a call to an external command? or are you wanting something with encryption to use with your call to aspnet_iisreg? Your question isnt so clear.

Comment: The first one you said :) so a .NET class that does aspnet_iisreg functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, but there is no such class...at least not in .net out of the box. You can build one or maybe someone else has built one.